# Relationship between changes in Currency against basket of currencies and inflation

Tags: inflation, international-trade, exchange-rates, international-economics

Sorry I'm not an economist, but I was wondering if there was a general country by country guide to how inflation there changes with response to a change in the currency's value against a basket of other currencies. I would naively expect an inverse correlation, but I'm not sure if this is proportional?

I'm just interested as after the Brexit vote, the UK pound has declined in value by 20% and am curious as to how much of this would be expected to show up in inflation.

I think it might be complicated by the state of the world economy (if no-ones able to sell, suppliers might have to lower prices), the state of employment (high unemployment might suppress any price rises, and the nature of the economy (ratio of services to manufacturing sector).